# Connecting Synergy between two computers on a Work Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, synergy

I bought Synergy and successfully use it between my Mac and my Windows 10 laptop on my home server. But when I bring these same two computers to work, and am using the same work wi-fi, Synergy no longer works. I imagine it's because my work wifi has a firewall that prevents my two computers from communicating.

My question is what methods can I use to get around this? I heard that connecting my two computers with an ethernet crossover cable will work. Are there any other methods that don't involve cables? I would like a solution that can be done wirelessly if possible. I'm looking for any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: "I would like a solution that can be done wirelessly if possible." Windows 10 supports turning a 802.11 adapter into a virtual hotspot/router.  However that still connects you to the network you don't have authority to reconfigure.  So there isn't a wireless solution to a crossover cable

Comment: This question is about reconfiguring a work environment network and is therefore off-topic on Super User.

Comment: are you setting your client computer to connect to the new ip address of your server computer? I dont see why it would be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a crossover cable. It was surprisingly straightforward and simple. I'm able to have each computer wirelessly connected to the network but my 2 laptops are connected to each other via crossover ethernet so that synergy works for my software KVM.